# Check equals of tags in array

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, tags, compare

Good day!
I have archive page, that displays all posts tags in sidebar.
In Archive page i have loop:

```
global $b;
        $i=1;
        $b=0;
        while( have_posts() ){
            the_post();
            global $arch_postID;
            global $b;
            if($i == $num_fetch && $sidebar == 'both-sidebar' ) {
            echo '<div class="blog-item' . $item_index . ' gdl-divider ' . $item_class . ' mb30">'; 
            $arch_postID[] = get_the_ID();
            echo $i;
            }elseif($i == $num_fetch) {
            echo '<div class="blog-item' . $item_index . ' gdl-divider ' . $item_class . ' mb20">'; 
            $arch_postID[] = get_the_ID();
            echo $i;
            }else{  
            echo '<div class="blog-item' . $item_index . ' gdl-divider ' . $item_class . ' mb50">';
            $arch_postID[] = get_the_ID();
            echo $i;
            }
            $b++;
            $i++;
```

In function.php for sidebar i have:

```
  global $arch_postID;
    global $b;
    global $archive_uri;    
    if ( !empty($arch_postID) && is_archive() ){         
        echo '<style>.archive-hide-side{display:none;}</style>';
        for($i = 0; $i <= $b-1; $i++){
        $array_keys = array_keys($arch_postID);
        $terms_array = wp_get_post_terms($arch_postID[$i],'vip');  // Get terms for post_id in array( $arch_postID[0], $arch_postID[1] ... )
        $terms_array_next = wp_get_post_terms($arch_postID[$i+1],'vip'); // Get terms for post_id in array( $arch_postID[1], $arch_postID[2] ... )
        $terms_array_last = wp_get_post_terms($arch_postID[$b-1],'vip'); // Get terms for $arch_postID[$i = last]
        $terms_array_first = wp_get_post_terms($arch_postID[0],'vip'); // Get terms for first post ID
        for($a = 0; $a <= count($a)+1; $a++){
        $name_array = $terms_array[$a]->name;
        $name_array_next = $terms_array_next[$a]->name;
        $name_array_last = $terms_array_last[$a]->name;
        $name_array_first= $terms_array_first[$a]->name;
            if( $name_array == $name_array_next or $name_array_next == $name_array_last or $name_array_last == $name_array_first ){ // check if next term->name is similar to previous of last, or first
        $name_array_next = NULL; // assigned NULL to value of term->name
        $name_array_last = NULL; // assigned NULL to value of term->name
        $name_array_first = NULL; // assigned NULL to value of term->name
            echo '<div style="color:black">'. $arch_postID[$i] .' || '. $name_array .'</div>';      // Display term->name values without next or previous term->name
        }
        }   
        }
    
    }
```

This code works like - prntscr.com/7rrozc - displays all tags( on right side ) and post ID(on left side ) divided by "||" from current archive page posts.

### End result:

I need to display only one tag, if it similar to another.

---

I have two posts, their tags: first post( "vip 1", "vip 2", "vip 3", "OTHER" ), second post( "vip 1", "vip 2", "OTHER 2").

---

In sidebar must be displayed "vip 1", "vip 2","vip 3","OTHER","OTHER 2".

---

I'm stuck on that question for two days, i have no solution in my mind... If someone knows how to do that, pls help me out. I would be happy for a little hint.

---

P.S. Thanks for you help and time!

Comment: [offtopic] A code can become vvvvvvvvvery unclear if you use non-saying variables. :-)

Comment: Sorry, i posted testing version of code. Change some code for better understanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution, works great!

```
$Path=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$Prev_path=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$URI='http://gradrich.tmweb.ru'.$Path;
global $arch_postID;
global $b;
global $archive_uri;
global $brr;
if ( !empty($arch_postID) && is_archive() ){ 
    for($i = 0; $i <= $b-1; $i++){  
    $terms_array = wp_get_post_terms($arch_postID[$i],'super_vip');
    for($a = 0; $a <= 100; $a++){//goes a 100 time from 0, to show all parameters from wp_get_post_terms array
    $terms_name[] = $terms_array[$a]->name;// create array of terms->name
    $terms_slug[] = $terms_array[$a]->slug;// create array of terms->slug
    }           
    }   
    $result_name = array_unique($terms_name);// check name array for unique variables 
    $result_slug = array_unique($terms_slug);// check slug array for unique variables 
    for($f = 0, $s = 0; $f <= count($terms_name), $s <= count($terms_slug); $f++, $s++){// do loop for all unique variables
    if(!empty($result_name[$f]) && !is_category() || !empty($result_slug[$s]) && !is_category()){//check if variables not empty than get proper name and slug from two arrays
    echo '<div class="tagCloud-cover" id="cat-hide"><a href="'. $URI .'+'. $result_slug[$s] .'" >+</a><a href="'. get_post_type_archive_link() .''. $result_slug[$s] .'" rel="tag">' . $result_name[$f] . '</a><a href="'. $Prev_path .'" >-</a></div>';
    } else{
    }
    }
}
```